# renderscript support mode in android studio

Tags: android

Hi get this error while trying to build a project i imported in android studio

> Could not find method renderscriptSupportMode() for arguments [false]
>   on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main,
>   minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=14, mCodename='null'},
>   targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=19, mCodename='null'},
>   renderscriptTargetApi=19, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null,
>   applicationId=com.jams.music.player, testApplicationId=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null,
>   testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
>   mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
>   mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.

How do i do away with this error please anyone

Answer (score 9):

0.14.0 (2014/10/31) Renamed a few properties to make things more consistent:

- BuildType.runProguard -> minifyEnabled
- BuildType.zipAlign -> zipAlignEnabled
- BuildType.jniDebugBuild -> jniDebuggable
- BuildType.renderscriptDebug -> renderscriptDebuggable
- ProductFlavor.renderscriptSupportMode -> renderscriptSupportModeEnabled
- ProductFlavor.renderscriptNdkMode -> renderscriptNdkModeEnabled

so renderscriptSupportMode rename to renderscriptNdkModeEnabled

Comment: Azu Thank you very much that worked !! am new to android studio and not quite familiar.I have gotten rid of all the errors but my project wont build i get this error"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task '' not found in root project 'JamsMusicPlayer-master'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
"

Comment: may by your app project dependent on a project named 'JamsMusicPlayer-master',something like this in you build.gralde--compile project(':BitmapWorker').plz check you build.gradle

Comment: Hi i managed to fix the build problems and it was about the build.gradle thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though @Azu has mentioned it in the answer, the part you are looking for is :

> renderscriptSupportMode -> renderscriptSupportModeEnabled

in your gradle file.

This is because the directives of gradle changed.