# How Do I Solve Android Gradle Plugin Error On Android Studio 3.1.1?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I upgraded Android Gradle plugin to version 3.1.1 and Gradle to Version 4.4. I got the error. How can I solve it?. Please, Anyone.

> Could not find method flavorDimension() for arguments [market] on
>   ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=google, dimension=null,
>   minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null,
>   renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null,
>   applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={},
>   testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null,
>   resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={},
>   mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
>   mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor. Open File

My (OLD) build.gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'XXXXXX'
                keyPassword 'XXXXXX'
                storeFile file('../XXXXXX.jks')
                storePassword 'XXXXXX'
            }
        }

        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.XXX.XXX'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 5
            versionName "5.0.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
        }

        productFlavors {
            dev {
                // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
                // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
                minSdkVersion 21
            }
            prod {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
                minSdkVersion 16
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        // my lib
        compile project(':cdroid')
        compile project(':videoview')

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4'
        compile 'nz.co.delacour.exposure-core:exposurevideoplayer:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
        compile 'fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.5.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

(I still see the error) I modified my build.gradle to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'XXXXX'
                keyPassword 'XXXXX'
                storeFile file('../XXXXX.jks')
                storePassword 'XXXXX'
            }
        }

        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.XXXXX.XXXXX'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 5
            versionName "5.0.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
        }

        flavorDimensions "minApi"

        productFlavors {
            dev {
                // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
                // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
                minSdkVersion 21
                dimension "minApi"
            }
            prod {
                // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
                minSdkVersion 16
                dimension "minApi"
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        // my lib
        compile project(':cdroid')
        compile project(':videoview')



        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
        compile 'nz.co.delacour.exposure-core:exposurevideoplayer:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        compile 'fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:5.5.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My New Error iS

> Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: You have no fancy specification for the `productFlavours`. Why don't you just remove the block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [renderscript support mode in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617902/renderscript-support-mode-in-android-studio)

Comment: Try turning off Instant run possible  [Google issue 72811718](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718)  bug in A.S. `3.1` , `3.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Gradle plugin version 3.0, all flavors must be assigned to a flavor dimension.

```
flavorDimensions "minApi"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
        dimension "minApi"
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
        minSdkVersion 16
        dimension "minApi"
    }
}
```

Also, you should be using the latest tools version and you should update various other parts of your build.gradle file (for instance, `compile` is deprecated and should be replace with `implementation` or, sometimes, `api`) For more information, see [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just change `buildToolsVersion` of `build.gradle`**(app)** and set it to `'27.0.3'` sync the gradle.

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

the gradle 4.4 required flavour dimension, define default flavour dimension in you app build.gradle

```
android { 
    ...
    flavorDimensions "default"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But after some research I came up with the code below, everything working fine now. Hopefully, this might helpful to someone else.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.APPNAME.androidapp"
        minSdkVersion 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        production {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "APPNAME"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
        }
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "APPNAME Stg"
            applicationIdSuffix ".stg"
        }

        development {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "APPNAME Dev"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```